# Get all championships that are teams in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a tournament, a tournament can have many >

```
public function championships()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Championship::class);
}
```

and a Championship hasOne Category. In Category, I have the `isTeam` attribute.

Now I need a function that get me all the championships that have the `isTeam = 1` in Category table.

```
public function teamChampionships()
{

}
```

Of course, I have defined : `$tournament->championships`, `$championship->category`

In my controller, I get all of them:

```
        $tournament = Tournament::with('championship.category')->find($tournament->id);
```

Any idea???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$tournament = Tournament::with(['championships' => function ($query) {
    $query->whereHas('category', function($subquery) {
        $subquery->where('isTeam', '=', 1);
    });
}])->get();
```

If the above doesn't work, try a different approach. Define `isTeam()` scope in Category model

```
public function scopeIsTeam($query) {
   return $query->where('isTeam', 1);
}
```

Then you can use it like this

```
$tournament = Tournament::with('championships.categoryIsTeam')
->find($tournament->id);
```

Even better, create another scope in Championship that loads only teams

```
public function categoryTeam() {
   return $this->hasOne(Category::class)->isTeam();
}
```

Sorry for too much information. One of those should do the job.

Comment: Tx for your help, I always forget how to do it